# Ansible and vault

Tags: ansible

I want to store my user's public keys in vault instead of a file.
How should i change my playbook:

```yaml
 name: push users public_keys
  authorized_key:
    state: present
    user: admin
    key: ""{{ lookup('file', '/path/to/your/www_id_rsa.pub') }}""
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way could be storing your vault variables in a file or encrypt a string. 
I'll show the use of file:

1. `ansible-vault create vault_vars.yml` (You'll be asked to create a password)
2. In the `vault_vars.yml` you create a normal variable containing the public_key: `pub_key: "rsa..."`
3. Include the file in your playbook:

   ```
      vars_files:
        - vault_vars.yml
   ```

You can access the variable from the vault just like you would with a variable being defined inside the playbook: `{{ pub_key }}`

An example printing the variable from the vault:

4. ```
    - hosts: server
      vars_files:
        - vault_vars.yml
      tasks:
      - debug: msg="{{pub_key}}"
   ```
5. Running playbook: `ansible-playbook playbook.yml --ask-vault-pass`

You can either use `--ask-vault-pass` (being prompted for password) or `--vault-password-file` (storing your vault password in a file)

**EDIT**
After reading the question again, and you stated you did not want to use a file meaning the solution would be as suggested below: Encrypt the string.
Personally I am not a big fan of encrypting strings and then put them directly in the playbook. I prefer to encrypt the file instead, making it easier to add/change values if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get the point of encrypting a public key. You usually want to do this for private keys (or any other kind of sensitive data like passwords, tokens...).

Meanwhile, if you really want to do that, you don't need to change anything to your playbook. You just have to encrypt the file containing your public key:

```
ansible-vault encrypt --ask-vault-pass /path/to/your/www_id_rsa.pub
```

Once this is done, ansible will automagically detect this is a vault encryted file when you try to use it and it will decrypt it on the fly. For this to work, you will of course have to provide the same vault password when you execute the playbook (or you will get an error saying that the vault could not be decrypted).

```
ansible-playbook -i my_inventory --ask-vault-pass my_playbook.yml
```

For more info on different options to provide the vault pass/id see: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html